# How to correctly apply fft function to a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, fft

Why do I get this error while applying `fft` (Fast Fourier Transform) to a data frame? If I use the same function on each variable by itself there is no error.

```
df<-read.table(text="pregnant glucose blood skin INSULIN MASS  DIAB AGE CLASS  predict_probability 
                                  1     106    70   28     135 34.2 0.142  22     0       0.15316285       
               1      91    54   25     100 25.2 0.234  23     0       0.05613959       
               4     136    70    0       0 31.2 1.182  22     1       0.54034794       
               9     164    78    0       0 32.8 0.148  45     1       0.64361578       
               3     173    78   39     185 33.8 0.970  31     1       0.79185196       
               11     136    84   35     130 28.3 0.260  42     1       0.31927737       
               0     141    84   26       0 32.4 0.433  22     0       0.41609308       
               3     106    72    0       0 25.8 0.207  27     0       0.10460090       
               9     145    80   46     130 37.9 0.637  40     1       0.67061324       
               10     111    70   27       0 27.5 0.141  40     1       0.16152296       
               ",header=T)
```

If I write `fft(df$pregnant)` I get the needed results but I try to use it on the whole data frame `fft(df)` I get this error:

> Error in fft(df) : non-numeric argument

Comment: The idea was to get more information per column and then add the new info as a new column in the data frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use only the numeric columns:

```
    apply(df,2,function(x) fft(as.numeric(x)))
```